# How to switch between activities without using intents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I just got an interview question and I really cannot figure it out...

The question is: If you have three activities A, B and C, how do you go from activity A to B, from B to C and then A to C sequentially without using intents?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't take my word on this, but the answer is: You can't.

Comment: You answer, "You can't". Then you ask if he's serious and if so you look for a new job because that guy doesn't know what he's talking about. At least there is no "good" way that I know of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after reading a few more times I could see what the interviewer may *possibly* mean but you are still using `Intents`. You will need them to get through each. But once you get to `C` you could get to `A` without an `Intent` if you  call `finish()` in `B` before going to `C`. Either way, unless I am terribly missing something, it seems like he could have asked a million better questions. I would have asked for.

Technically, an application, AFAIK, could never be launched without an `Intent` because you use `Intent Filters` (`launch`, `main`) in the `manifest` to start an app.

Comment: Nice catch. But the question asks: `.... and then A to C sequentially without using intents?`. If only it was `C` to `A`...

Comment: @vikram right, that's why I said I would ask for clarification. This is the ONLY way that I can see there being a reasonable answer to the question except for "you can't". Because this way you could answer "then A to C sequentially without using intents"

Comment: You are right. `C to A sequentially` makes more sense. OP should definitely hassle his/her interviewer.

Comment: @codeMagic Thanks, I finally understood what he was asking about..I agree the question is very confusing. As you denoted here what the interviewer cares is the "calling finish() in B" part.

Comment: @Sherman_Meow I'm glad I could help and make some kind of sense out of it.

Answer (score 0):

you can't, because [all of the methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29) used to start an `Activity` require an `Intent` in their parameters